# How do I replace one character occurrence in a string?

Tags: java, string, replace

How would I replace a string like "Hello" with "Helko", only replacing the second L but not the first?

Comment: What if there's two l's in the string, should it only replace the second and not the third?

Comment: replace("Hello", "Helko") ? or replace("ll", "lk") ?

Comment: However you do it you will be creating a new string since strings are immutable.

Comment: I wanted to replace one instance of a character with another, like "aaaaa" with "aabaa", where only the third 'a' is replaced with 'b', but not the others.

Comment: is this part of some regex tutorial? So using matching groups? Something like: "l(l)"gm ? So the group matches on the second "l". Would also match "Hell" oder "Hellllllooo". But no solution is complete without a regex :D

Comment: Convert the String to a char array, replace characters, convert the char array back to String for display.

Answer (score 1):

Use replaceAll with regular expression:

```
System.out.println("Hello".replaceAll("((?!^).*?|[^l]*l.*?)l","$1k"));
```

Comment: This will replace the `l` when there is only a single `l` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

*Simple Approach (based on excluding the second `l`)*:

- Search for first index of `l` using `indexOf` and do another search for `l` but this time start searching from *`firstL` + 1* which will lead to the second index `l` if exist!
- Do a test if there is second `l`, If So *Exclude* the second `l` by using `substring` which take only the first part *(start from zero till `secondL`)* and second part *(start from `secondL`+1 till the end)*, Concatenate them with `k`.

```java
public static String removeSecondL(String str) {
    int firstL = str.indexOf('l');
    int secondL = str.indexOf('l', firstL+1);
    if(secondL != -1) {
        String firstPart = str.substring(0, secondL);
        String secondPart = str.substring(secondL + 1);
        return firstPart + 'k' + secondPart;
    }
    return str;
}
```

**Tests:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeSecondL("Hello")); // Helko
    System.out.println(removeSecondL("lololo")); // lokolo
    System.out.println(removeSecondL("no l")); // no l
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Another Approach:* Convert the String into a char array, and declare a variable `lFound` gonna look for the first occurrence of letter `l`, if it found next `l` will be converted to `k` and exit the loop by `break`.

```java
String str =  "Hello";
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
boolean lFound = false;
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if(lFound) {
        if(chars[i] == 'l') 
        {
            chars[i] = 'K';
            break;
        }
    }else {
        lFound = chars[i] == 'l'; //if(chars[i] == 'l') lFound = true;
    }
}
System.out.println(chars); //HelKo
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lately**, I turned to the conversation and I saw you writing:

> I wanted to replace one instance of a character with another, like "aaaaa" with "aabaa", where only the third 'a' is replaced with 'b', but not the others.

Just follow second approach I posted with additional tests.

```java
public static char[] removeSpecificChar(String str, char a, char b, int position) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    int pos = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if(pos == position) {
            if(chars[i] == a) 
            {
                chars[i] = b;
                break;
            }
        }else {
            pos += (chars[i] == a) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    return chars;
}
```

*Test:*

```java
String str =  "aaaaa";
System.out.println(removeSpecificChar(str, 'a', 'b', 3));
```

*Print:*

```
aabaa
```